# How CSS influence loading times

Tags: html, css, loading

I'm pretty new to HTML&CSS, and I'm building my first website.
My head tag looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" /> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/739d414f-2430-436c-b2cf-5b84cc45995c.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css"> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/projects2.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:680px)" href="css/tablet.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:1400px)" href="css/desktop.css">
    <title>Yulie Wollman | Projects </title>
</head>
```

I have 2 questions regarding to the CSS:
First, is multiple external CSS files influence my loading times? is it better to merge them into one big CSS file?

Secondly, will the media screen css link tags influence my loading times on smaller resolutions than 680px/1400px?

Thank you,
Boaz Keren Gil

Comment: Question 1: yes, question 2: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTTP 1.0/1.1 every single HTTP request comes with overhead so the fewer requests the better.

You should work to keep the CSS segregated for your ease of coding at the server but combine them and *then* serve a single CSS compiled "file" to the client.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');
include('css/normalize.css');
include('css/mobile.css');
include('css/projects2.css');
?>
```

If you're running Apache you'll need to ensure you can execute PHP inside of the file type you use (e.g. .css)...

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .css
```

...just make sure that you serve the correct mime **FROM** the file itself when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I would've said that one request is always better that lots of requests, so one big css is , in this case better, BUT if you have **really** big css file for lots of pages, and you'll load it on every page even if 99% of it's style are not necessary - that's not good at all. So decide it for your own case: few pages, small css - merge it to one, big project, lots of pages - separate requests on each.

And for second - nop,they will not.

Answer (score 0):

Overall question Yes, it does influence load time. Each external css file is a additional request so it does add overhead.

However, the browser will cache the css so the next request will not suffer that much.

In general, if all pages in the site use the same css I would combine them and minimize them once deployed into your production environment

There are tools available like YSlow from Yahoo or Page Speed from Google that give you great insight in what is happening.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=nl

You can also use plugins for your browser to see the effect.

Comment: Those tools are great, didn't know about them. That actually helped a lot figuring out what's going on in my website.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommended to reduce the number of http requests, especially for the websites targeting mobile browsers. The mobile networks have usually high latency (could be 300ms per request), then for 10 referenced files (css, javascript) it is 300 * 10 = 3 seconds loading time.